# How do I highlight C libraries in listings?

Tags: color, listings, syntax-highlighting

I am using the `listings` package to typeset the following C code in Latex

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Latex code for this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{language=C}

\definecolor{dark-bg}{HTML}{0D1117}
\definecolor{cwhite}{HTML}{E6EDF3}
\definecolor{identifier}{HTML}{79C0FF}
\definecolor{comment}{HTML}{8B949E}
\definecolor{string}{HTML}{A5D6FF}
\definecolor{keyword}{HTML}{FF7B72}

\lstdefinestyle{dark}{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\color{white},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{dark-bg},
    identifierstyle=\color{identifier},
    commentstyle=\color{comment},
    keywordstyle=\color{keyword},
    directivestyle=\color{keyword}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=dark]{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This highlights `#include` but doesn't highlight the libraries.

How do I do this?